# Git fetch commit id using tagid

Tags: git, gitlab

in my master branch I have a condition to fetch the commit id by using Tagid.Tried with git rev-parse 0.0.xx. This is giving me hash value only. Is there any way to get the current commit id based on tagid.

Comment: If `0.0.xx` is a tag, then the hash returned by `git rev-parse 0.0.xx` is right the commit id (in almost all cases).

Comment: Thanks. is there any way to get original commit id and NOT hash?

Answer (score 2):

I missed somthing in the comment.

If `0.0.xx` is an annotated tag, which has a log message, `git rev-parse 0.0.xx` returns the hash of the tag object.

To get the commit id it points to, use `git rev-parse 0.0.xx^{}` instead.

If `0.0.xx` is a lightweight tag, both `git rev-parse 0.0.xx` and `git rev-parse 0.0.xx^{}` return the commit id.

So regardless of the type of the tag, `git rev-parse <tag>^{}` always returns the commit it points to.

See [gitrevisions](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtemegemv0998em).